# Update Sqlite database only works once

Tags: sqlite, sql-update, xcode4.3

I have an sqlite database and it's loaded into a tableview, now when i click a row to see its details..i go to another view controller in which details are displayed and a AddToFav button exists.
When i click it..and go to another view controller...i can see the changes correctly, my database is updating correctly, but if i try to add another entry..i notice that my database is not updated anymore..The addToFav button only updates the database once. Any ideas?
This is my Addbut IBaction :

```
- (IBAction)AddButClick:(UIButton *)sender {



    [AddBut setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"apple-logo copy.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [AddBut setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"apple-logo copy.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    Favo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1000000];



    @try {
      //  NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        // NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dictionary.sqlite"];
        //NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"authorsDb2.sqlite"];
        //     NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"FinalDb.sqlite"];
        //NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"xxJuridique-FINAL-OK.sqlite"];
     //   [self createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];


   //     NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.sqlite"];
      //  [self.tableView reloadData];

        sqlite3_stmt *compiled_statement1;

        if(sqlite3_open([PathDB UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK) {



//            UIAlertView *DbO = [[UIAlertView alloc]
//                                 initWithTitle:@"PATH" message:@"Database still open !" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
//            
//            [DbO show];
            NSString *formatedSql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE Sheet1 SET Fav = 'YES' WHERE field3 = '%@'" , authorNAme2];

//            UIAlertView *messageAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
//                                         initWithTitle:@"Query" message:formatedSql delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
//            
//            [messageAlert show];
//            
            UIAlertView *PAth = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                 initWithTitle:@"PATH" message:PathDB delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

            [PAth show];
           // NSLog(PathDB);

            const char *sql = [formatedSql UTF8String];
            NSLog(@" !!!!!!!! In the middle of it !!!!!!!!!!!!");
            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &compiled_statement1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
                NSLog(@"!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!ERRRRROOOOOOORRRRRRRRR!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
                //NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
            }

            NSLog(@"This is the query %@",formatedSql);

        }
   //     sqlite3_bind_text(compiled_statement1, 1, [authorNAme2 UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);


        int success = sqlite3_step(compiled_statement1);

        // sqlite3_reset(compiled_statement1);
        if (success != SQLITE_ERROR) {
            NSLog(@"Successfully inserted");
            sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(db);
        }

//        
//        BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
//        
//        if(!success)
//        {
//            NSLog(@"Cannot locate database file '%@'.", dbPath);
//        }
//        if(!(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK))
//        {
//            NSLog(@"An error has occured: %@", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
//            
//        }


        // const char *sql = "SELECT F_Keyword FROM wordss";  
        const char *sql = "SELECT * FROM Sheet1";
        NSLog(@"Successfully selected from database");
        sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %@", sqlite3_errmsg(db));


        }else{


            NSLog(@"Got in the else tag");

            while (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement)==SQLITE_ROW /*&& PAss == NO*/) {

                NSLog(@"Got in the while tag");

                Author * author = [[Author alloc] init];
                NSLog(@"Author initialized");

                author.name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement,10)];
                NSLog(@"Initialization ok");
           //     NSLog(author.name);

                if(/*author.name == @"NO" &&*/ HighLighted == NO){
                    //const char *sql2 = "INSERT INTO Sheet1 ";

                    [AddBut setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"apple-logo copy.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    NSLog(@"We have not selected it as fav yet");
                  //  [AddBut setSelected:NO]; //btn changes to normal state
                    NSLog(@"The button was NOt highlighted and now is");
                    HighLighted = YES;
                     break;

                }

                else
                {

                    NSLog(@"We have selected it as fav");

                    [AddBut setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"apple-logo.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    [AddBut setSelected:NO]; //btn changes to normal state
                    NSLog(@"The button was highlighted and now is NOt");


                    HighLighted = NO;
                     break;

                   // [self viewDidLoad];
                  //  PAss = YES;

                }
         //       [Favo release];

         //       NSLog(Favo);

//                author.name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement,2)];
//                author.title = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement,2)];
//                author.genre = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 4)];
//                [theauthors addObject:author];
            }
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {

        NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %@", sqlite3_errmsg(db));

    }
    @finally {
        //   sqlite3_finalize(sqlStatement);
     //   sqlite3_close(db);

        UIAlertView *fin = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                                initWithTitle:@"Query" message:@"DOne with Click Button" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

                   [fin show];

        return Favo;
    }
```

Comment: You open and close the database everytime you do something with it?

Comment: how do you suggest doing it ? I'm a newb in xcode

Comment: Holding the sqlite database handle in the app delegate and only closing when the app goes into the background.  In other database architectures, connecting to the database is extremely expensive...

Comment: can you provide a sample or documentation on this matter?

Comment: No not really.  The best thing to do is create wrapper classes for `SqliteDatabase` and `SqliteStatement` that make it easy to manage the lifetime of those objects and you could easily just pass the `SqliteDatabase` object to each new object you create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @crazyCreator for your answer !!!!

[self authorList2];
[self.tableView reloadData];